# Nivo Slider not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I am sorry to post question hich was here before, but this is driving me crazy and no fix is working.

Website is http://www.ipmgroup.org everything is working fine, just Nivo Slider does not fire. This also causes that no javascript in the file ipm.main.js fires. If i comment the nivoslider, everything works just fine.

Could somebody please look at it if they can see the flaw?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out. 
For people with the same problem. Any settings ending with number, in my case animSpeed:500 should be at the bottom of your nivoSlider call.